# PHP - basic select query returning only the first row of mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been running the query oh phpMyAdmin and it shows all the rows, but my query in php only returns the first row.

```
$result = $mydb -> query("SELECT * FROM music_sheet WHERE category='".$_REQUEST["submitter"]."'"); 

print(count($result)); //always returns 1

for ($x = 0; $x < count($result); $x++) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
}
```

Comment: What is `$_REQUEST["submitter"]` ?

Comment: `count($result)` probably doesn't mean what you think it means.  (Unless `$result` is designed to be countable, you'll probably just get a 1 due to the result resource existing as a single value.)

Comment: Its just a result from my html form

Comment: You should really use parameter binding since you're already using `mysqli`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, here's why `count()` is returning `1`. [From the manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

> If the parameter is not an array or not an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned. There is one exception, if array_or_countable [*the parameter*] is NULL, 0 will be returned.

Since `$result` is a **resource** (object) that is returned from your query, not an array which you would get within your loop getting the actual data out of the resource, `count($resource)` will return `1`.

Your solution is of course to use `mysqli_num_rows()`. To retrieve data from this resource, you need to loop over it as you are doing, but either use `mysqli_num_rows()` in place of `count()`, or other (more common) ways of looping through a result set, like so:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `mysqli_num_rows($result)` function to count rows which are returned by MySQLi query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
// write your code...
}
```

Use this instead of the for loop

Answer (score -1):

the first thing that the query method returns to you is a resource/object. This query method always return a mysqli_result object for successful queries using SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries . For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE. For that reason it always count it as "1", what you should try is:

```
$result = $mydb -> query("SELECT * FROM music_sheet WHERE category='".$_REQUEST["submitter"]."'"); 

$numRows = $result->num_rows;

print(count($numRows)); //it should show you the total amount of rows

//verify the amount of rows before of tryng to loop over it
if ($numRows) {
    while($object = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
    //for each loop you will have an object with the attributes of the row
    echo $object->song_name; 
    }
}
```

This should work,

Regards.